# How to make functions not accessible in URL but can be called through AJAX request in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

> I want my CRUD not to be accessible to the URL but can be called through ajax request. Can't find solution anywhere. Any help will be much appreciated

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Class_List extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        $this->load->model('mdl_class_list');
    }

    function index(){

    }

    function form($id = NULL){

    }

    function create(){

    }

    function read($term_id = NULL){

    }

    function update(){

    }

    function delete(){

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Every function set condition :

```
if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
   exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
```

or either put it in constructor.

Comment: this just checks that `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header is set.  Well it may work on the surface, you can probably send that header if you want to.  It's not a guarantee that it will prevent anything.  `Checks to see if the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH server header has been set, and returns boolean TRUE if it is or FALSE if not`  [CI Doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::is_ajax_request)

Comment: it will check the request is ajax or not....suppose it another request it will redirect.

Comment: Even if it does prevent it (Which it doesn't) you can just use postman or similar to simulate an Ajax request, and call it.  The fact is `not to be accessible to the URL` AJAX by it's nature uses a URL.

Comment: thank you sir. one more thing, if i will put it in the constructor, how to exempt other functions? example in my index or form functions

Comment: constructor call before any function call so it will first check in constructor.

Comment: sorry i dont understand, i'm still a student. can u please simplify or give some example :)

Comment: when you call any function first constructor call and then your function call in OOPS.